# how to show time ago in a label in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i have a table for article and this table include a field named "dateofSubmitArticle"
when i show the article i want show in a label in repeater that how much time ago this article  submit in database 
datasource of repeater is

```
 var n = (from a in DataContext.Context.Articles
                 join u in DataContext.Context.Users
                 on a.UserID equals u.UserID
                 orderby a.ArticleID descending
                 where a.IsConfirmByAdmin == true
                 select new { 
                 ArticleID=a.ArticleID,
                 ArticleTitle=a.ArticleTitle,
                 ArticleSummery=a.ArticleSummery,
                 SubmitDate=a.SubmitDate,
                 Username=u.Username,
                 ArticleImageName=a.ArticleImageName
                 }).Take(15);
        rptArticleTitle.DataSource = n;
        rptArticleTitle.DataBind();
```

Comment: nice to see the datasource, but can we see also any effort you put in?

Comment: `var timePast = DateTime.Now - SubmitDate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timespan class. To achieve your goal, put a asp label and hidden field in the repeater, bind the SubmitDate to that hidden field.

HTML:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="Submitted" />
<asp:Hidden runat="server" id="val" Value='<%#Eval("SubmitDate")%>'/>
```

Now in repeaters ItemDataBound find the label and hidden and use the code below.

```
void ItemDataBound()
{
  if(e.Item.ItemType == DataItemType || e.Item.ItemType ==AlternatingItemType)
  {
      var lbl = e.Item.FindControl(lable_id) as Label;
      var hid = e.Item.FindControl(hidden_id) as Hidden;

      if(lbl !=null and hid !=null)
      {
          var val = DateTime.Parse(hid.Value);
         // Get the TimeSpan of the difference. 
         TimeSpan elapsed = now.Subtract(val); 
         lbl.Text = string.Format("{0} days ago", elapsed.Days);
      }

  }
}
```